# How can I fix my C program?

Tags: c

I thought I fixed my code so I deleted my old post.  My question is trying to determine what is wrong with my code.  I am testing a string to see if it meets two conditions.  It must contain only alpha characters and at least one vowel.  Where do I begin?

```
int check_word(char);

main()
{
   char array[100];
   int result;

   printf("Enter a word:\n");
   gets(array);

   check_word(array);
   {
   if result == 1;
   printf("Word is valid\n");

   else
       printf ("Word is notvalid.");
   }
   return 0;
}



int check_word(char a)
{
   if ( a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z' )
      a = a + 'a' - 'A';   /* Converting to lower case */

   if ( (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') && (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) 
      result = 1;
   else 
       result = 0;

   return result;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We aren't here to do hw for you. @DavidJashi please be polite, this is the OP's first question and they deserve the benefit of the doubt

Comment: Never, *never*, use `gets`.  Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @jozefg Well, as he admitted it's the second one and rules deserve to be read.

Comment: I have gone through a few times and I guess I am confused on how to return the results of the check_word function.  I don't know how to pass that value to main in order to determine which statement should print.

Comment: Check word is declared as taking a `char`.  You are passing a `char *`.  Turn up the compiler warnings.

Comment: @user2625359: The `return` keyword in `check_word()` passes the value for you. In `main()`, you need to use `result = check_word(...);`. This will store the value returned in the variable named `result` that you have declared in `main()`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17900530/539810) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a few things you might want to look up:

- [isalpha](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt82b8z8(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [The C switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a(v=vs.80).aspx)
- The difference between an array and a single variable.
- Strings in C (effectively an array of char with a terminating 0)
- How return values work

#### EDIT: Here's a small exercise: "Fill the Gaps"

Fill each gap `...` with the semantically correct statement. **Explain** (i.e. reason about) why you have to write that specific statement there.

```
#include <...>
#include <...>

int is_vowel(int c)
{
    switch(c) {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    case 'e':
    ...
        return ...;
    }
    return ...;
}

int justalpha_hasvowel(... candidate)
{
    if(!candidate)
        return ...;

    int found_vowel = 0;
    for(char *c = candidate; *c; ...) {
        if(!isalpha(*c))
            return 0;
        found_vowel = is_vowel(*c) || ...;
    }
    return found_vowel;
}

... main(...)
{
   char array[100];
   int result;

   printf("Enter a word:\n");
   memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
   fgets(array, sizeof(array)-1, stdin);

   ... = justalpha_hasvowel(array);
   if(...) {
       printf("Word is valid\n");
   } else {
       printf ("Word is not valid.");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am working on the exercise.  I am using Visual Studio as my IDE if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Thanks. (I had to write a lot of isalnum recently, damn muscle memory).

Comment: I may have to come back to this.  I have been working on this for about 8 hours and my legs hurt.  I appreciate the assistance, I will give another crack at it shortly.

Comment: The isvowel identifier invades a reserved namespace in ISO C (all identifiers starting with is- and another lower case character). Better: is_vowel.

Comment: @Jens: Please specify where this namespace reservation is defined.

Comment: @datenwolf ISO C99 7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers in conjunction with 7.26.2 Character Handling (In a nutshell: `is[a-z]*` and `to[a-z]*` are reserved.) Oh, and `str[a-z]*` is also reserved by `<string.h>` so `string` is out too ;-)

Comment: @Jens: One could argue, that if you don't want to access global scope reserved identifiers, the local scoped masking of `string` is in order.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of problems:

```
int check_word(char);

main() /* int main(void) is better */
{
   char array[100];
   int result;

   printf("Enter a word:\n");
   gets(array); /* deprecated, use fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin) */

   /* check_word(array);  Do you want to check the first character or the whole string? */
   result = check_word(array[0]); /* the first character */
   /* if result == 1; Nops */
   if (result == 1) 
       printf("Word is valid\n");
   else
       printf ("Word is notvalid."); /* what about \n :) ? */

   return 0;
}

int check_word(char a)
{
   if ( a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z' )
      a = a + 'a' - 'A'; /* suggest tolower() */
   /* c is not initialized --------------------------------------------v */
   /* suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ */
   if ( (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') && (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
   /* or delete all this stuff  -------------------------------------^ from here */
      /*result = 1;*/ return 1;
   else 
      /* result = 0; */ return 0;

   /* return result; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 check_word(array);
   {
   if result == 1;
   printf("Word is valid\n");

   else
       printf ("Word is notvalid.");
   }
```

those code make no sense.Use this:

```
result = check_work(array);
if(result == 1)
    printf("Word is valid\n");
else 
    printf("Word id notValid\n");
```

Also,add `int result ;` at the begin of function `check_word`.

You should know this:

1.the  `result` in `main` is not the `result` in `check_word`.

2.`if(result ==1) ;` means do nothing when `(result == 1) == true`

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.

1. **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER use `gets`**; it *will* introduce a point of failure and a major security hole in your code.  It is no longer supported as of the 2011 C standard.  Use `fgets` instead.
2. Implicit typing of `main` is no longer supported as of the 1999 standard; use `int main( void )` instead.
3. You've declared `check_word` to take a single `char` value as an argument, but you're passing it an *array* of `char`, which means it receives a `char *` value<sup>1</sup>.  Based on the body of the function, it looks like you only want to pass a single character, so you would call it as

   ```
       if ( check_word( array[0] ) == 1 )
       {
         printf( "word is valid\n" );
       }
   ```
4. There are number of library functions that can make your `check_word` function much simpler: `isupper()` returns true of a character value is uppercase, `tolower()` converts a character value from uppercase to lowercase, `isalpha()` returns true if a character is a letter, etc.  You will need to `#include <ctype.h>` to use these functions.
5. You might want to factor out the vowel check into its own function, like so:

   ```
       int vowel( int c )
       {
         int lc = tolower( c );
         return ( lc == 'a' || lc == 'e' || 
                  lc == 'i' || lc == 'o' || 
                  lc == 'u' );
       }
   ```

   and then use it in the `check_word` function as

   ```
       if ( vowel( a ) && ...)
       {
         result = 1;
       }
   ```

   I'm assuming the `c` in the `(c >= 'a' && c <='z')` is a typo, and you meant to type `a`.  Again, this is where the `isaplha` library function comes in handy:

   ```
       if ( vowel( a ) && islapha( a ) )
       {
         result = 1;
       }
   ```

---

<sup>1.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.</sup>